# Determing whether or not the relationships in each problem are symmetric, transitive, and/or reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

For each of the following relations on the set of all integers, determine whether the relation is reflexive, symmetric, and/or transitive:

a. (,)∈ if and only if <.

b.     (,)∈ if and only ≥1.

c.  (,)∈ if and only =−.

d.     (,)∈ if and only =||

I've made some attempts at solving these of course, but have only yielded fitting answers for b and d, which I know are symmetric/transitive, and solely symmetric, respectively (unless I made some errors in deducing this which is definitely not out of the question). I even tried looking at post like the one below to determine whether or not what I was doing was correct, but it didn't provide much I could really use.
I appreciate your help and assistance

[Determine whether the relations are symmetric, antisymmetric, or reflexive.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275594/determine-whether-the-relations-are-symmetric-antisymmetric-or-reflexive)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For reflexive, for all $x$, is (a) $x<x$? (b) $x^2\ge1$? (c) $x=-x$? (d) $x=|x|$?

Answer (score 2):

In this type of exercise, you need to apply the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Homogeneous_relation) of these types of relations and you have to ask yourself the right questions:

- **Reflexivity** : for all $x$, is it true that
  $$
  x < x \text{ (a). }\\
  x^2 \ge 1 \text{ (b). }\\
  x = -x \text{ (c). }\\
  x = |x| \text{ (d). }
  $$
- **Symmetry** : for all $x$ and $y$, is it true that
  $$
  x<y \implies y<x \text{ (a). }\\
  xy \ge 1 \implies yx \ge 1 \text{ (b). }\\
  x = -y \implies y = -x \text{ (c). }\\
  x = |y| \implies y = |x| \text{ (d). }
  $$
- **Transitivity** : for all $x,y,z$, is it true that
  $$
  x<y \text{ and } y<z \implies x<z \text{ (a). }\\
  xy \ge 1 \text{ and } yz \ge 1 \implies xz \ge 1 \text{ (b). }\\
  x = -y \text{ and } y = -z \implies x = -z \text{ (c). }\\
  x = |y| \text{ and } y = |z| \implies x = |z| \text{ (d). }
  $$

Can you finish? If you have a question don't hesitate.

Comment: **Symmetry**:  for all $x$ **and $\mathbf y$** ...

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: Not a big deal; thanks for correcting.  I always remember that R, S, and T have 1, 2, and 3 variables, respectively

Comment: I'm looking through it now since I had to step out. I understand it for the most part